# Adding (and Finding) an element to a binary tree (NOT BST)

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, pseudocode

So I'm trying to put an element in a binary tree (not a search tree) in java. I looked everywhere, and all I can see are algorithms for inserting it into a binary *search* tree (and I want a simple binary tree). Given the value of the parent node, I need to set the left and right children. My plan looks like this:

```
public void addLeft(E elem, E parentVal) {
//Find node with parentVal
//Create node with element elem (call it newNode)
//Set the left child of the node with parentVal as newNode
}
```

The last 2 steps are fairly simple, so my real problem is finding the node with a given value.
In a search tree, it is an easy task, but in a normal binary tree, I don't know how to do it. I understand that it won't be efficient; as far as I know, to add an element to a given node in a normal binary tree, we have to traverse the entire tree to find that node. Any suggestions on how to do this? Assume there will be no repeats of numbers (all nodes have a unique element). I've tagged this as algorithm/pseudocode, so just a basic idea is all I need to get started (although code is appreciated as well).

Comment: In a binary (not search) tree you search by running over all the nodes of the tree and stopping when you find the result/have visited all the nodes. If there are no other issues, there is no sense in adding the complexity of a tree if you can get the same performance with a list.

Comment: @SJuan, yes, you run over the nodes, but how? Start by traversing down the left subtrees, and once you reach the end of the leftmost tree, do what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way of recursively traversing the tree and stopping when `parentVal` is found:

```
// returns true if the element has been added to this subtree
public boolean addLeft(E elem, E parentVal) {
    if (this.equals(parentVal)) {
        //Create node with element elem (call it newNode)
        //Set the left child of the node with parentVal as newNode
        return true;
    } else if (leftChild != null && leftChild.addLeft(elem, parentVal)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return rightChild != null && rightChild.addLeft(elem, parentVal);
    }
}
```

This is assuming that a node has access to its children through `leftChild` / `rightChild`.

Comment: Wouldn't this refer to the tree rather the node?

Comment: In order to use this for the whole tree, you simply call it on the root node.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in [Google code](https://code.google.com/p/jc-tree/) and in github search took me to this [Java implementation](https://github.com/stevesavia/BinaryTree)

Another quick raw write-up implementation is the [python implementation of Binary tree](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/binary-search-tree-library-in-python/). The heading for link is misleading, but check the entire write-up.

From the link here is a high level psuedo.,

```
class Node:
    ...
    def insert(self, data):
        """
        Insert new node with data

        @param data node data object to insert
        """
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)
```

Comment: Do you know what self refers to in this case? Is it the root, or the node in question, or what?